# How to efficiently copy recipients from old Gmail message

Tags: gmail

I am using Gmail webmail in Safari and Chrome on a Mac. Often I want to send a new message to all the same people as in an old email in my inbox. My workflow for this is as following:

- click `compose`
- find an old email, and click `show details`
- copy everything in `to:` and paste to new message
- copy `from:` and paste to new message
- find my own address and delete it

This workflow is very tedious, and there is a high risk that I do something wrong when copying the recipients. Is there a better way? -some shortcut or something that allows me to use `Reply to all` as a way to make a new message to all.

**EDIT:**

It has been suggested to use `Reply to all` and then edit the subject. The problem with that is that the email does not lose its connection to the previous thread. I have sent a test to myself and looking at the source(`Show original`), I can see the ID of the previous thread under `References:` and `In-Reply-To:`. Maybe I should not worry about this!? -or maybe there are e-mail clients, that sort the treads from these pieces of information, and not just the subject!?

**Example:**
By replying to a message, and sending it to myself, the source looks like this:
[image: Message source]

The ID, `...QYT_Q@...` is the ID of the message, that I made the reply to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply to the email then delete all the pre-populated content?

A 'reply' is really just a new email that contains the same subject, sometimes with RE: appended to it.

If you just delete this content (the subject and the mail body) then there's no link between this 'new' email, and the one you actually replied to - except it'll keep all the To: and Cc: information.

Comment: I do not think that the email loses its connection to the previous tread. I have send a test to myself, and looking at the source(`Show original`), I can see the ID of the previous tread under `References:` and `In-Reply-To:`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly more technical workaround. I copied the recipients, and since they're in the format of `username <email.address@emailprovider.com>,` I was able to get just the addresses by using a search and replace regex string. First, go to regex101.com. Select "substitution" in the function selection in the middle of the left side of the screen. Paste the recipients list into the test string text box and put the regex string `.*<(.*)>.*` into the regular expressions text box. Finally, in the "substitution" text box, put the regex string `$1`, and the email addresses will be in the text box below. In the end, it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Create an .ahk script to automate this process and bind it to a hotkey or trigger of your choosing, and you've got gold!

Comment: I could see that as pretty useful for someone who needs to send a lot of emails. If someone requests it I might have a project to do over Thanksgiving.

Answer (score 1):

- go in **Sent Mail**
- find an email that has recipients you want
- open it
- hit **Reply**
- click on "back arrow" (see gif bellow)
- select **Edit Subject** and edit it (note that it **must be different** than initial subject)
- delete body of the email
- write what you want and send it

[image]

**EDIT:**

**GIF:** **https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Lvs.gif** (open in new tab)

[image]

Comment: I do not think that the email loses its connection to the previous tread. I have send a test to myself, and looking at the source(`Show original`), I can see the ID of the previous tread under `References:` and `In-Reply-To:`.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I just double check it and it does loses its connection. like I wrote: you need to change Subject and delete old email body

Comment: Yes, but it is not enough. -see my question edit.

Comment: @hpekristiansen see my edit / proof

Comment: OK - that is strange, because that is not what happens, when I do it. -see added example.

Comment: I have the same problem as @hpekristiansen. Despite changing the subject and deleting all previous content, I see links in both In-Reply-To: and References: to the message I was responding to. Many email clients will thus hide it under a previous thread, confusing the reader.